# Writing to many replicas of MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, deployment, database-replication, replicaset

Let's say I have a distributed application that writes to the database. To decrease latency one of the instances (app + database) is hosted in Australia and another one is hosted in Europe. Both instances of database need to share the same data.

So what we are after here is data locality. The reason for it is obvious: we don't want users in Australia shooting requests to our database in Europe because that would increase latency.

The natural choice would be to deploy both instances of database in a one replica set. But it seems that with MongoDB you can write to [only one Mongo instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702416/mongodb-replica-set-write-on-secondary) within replica set.

What are the strategies with MongoDB to have two instances of database, sharing the same data, to which you can write to? Or is the MongoDB just a wrong choice for this requirement?

Comment: The link is correct. Replicas are to ensure high availability, and in some cases for heavy queries. Your usecase falls under sharding topic: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-data-by-location/ Virtually they "share" the data from the client point of view, it's just querying European data from Australia will take a little more time than the requests to the local shard.

Answer (score 1):

Huge subject, but i'll try to give you a short and simple answer :

As your two instances must share the same sata, you can't use [sharded cluster with zones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sharding-segmenting-data-by-location/) . But [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) can be your solution :

- Create a replica set with at least the following :

  - a server in a 'neutral' zone. It will be the primary server (set a priority higher). This server, as long as it still primary, will handle your write operations.
  - your two existing servers with lower priority.
- Set in your application [Read Preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) to 'nearest'. This way, your read operations will be handle by the server having the mower network latency, regardless of the Master/secondary roles of server.

But i highly recommand you to check the documentation, to see how correctly deploy this architecture. [Here's a good start](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/)

EDIT

Some consideration about this solution :

- This use case is one of the rare use case where it's better to read from secondaries. In general, prefer reading your data from MASTER, since replica set is done for high availability, not for scalability.
- If some of your data can be 'located' to be accessed faster, consider sharding collections as a better solution

Comment: Thanks! Are there any databases that handles it better or worse than Mongo? Or each mainstream database suffers from the same problem?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot answer, since my knowledges about databases essentially conceern mongodb. I'll add some consideration in my answer